# How to mask query param values in Linux

Tags: linux, bash, shell, replace

Need help on below requirement.

I have a file with list of URLs and need to mask query param values as shown in below example in Linux.

http://hostname:port/uri?data=value&data1=value2&data3=value3

to

http://hostname:port/uri?data=XXX&data1=XXX&data3=XXX

thanks

Comment: You can use python and https://docs.python.org/3/library/urllib.parse.html

Comment: it is simple task, what have you tried so far?

Comment: I tried sed command as follows sed 's/\=[0-9]\+/\=XXX/g', however in some URL the param value contains just alphabets, alpha numeric (in both case), Special characters (%20 etc).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you could replace any character that is not a `&`, it is more efficient than enumerating all possible ranges:

```
$ echo 'http://hostname:port/uri?data=value&data1=va%20lue2&data3=value3' | \
sed -r 's/=[^&]+/=XXX/g'

http://hostname:port/uri?data=XXX&data1=XXX&data3=XXX
```